# Update is not working for properties with formula in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have a hbm file which has the property shown below.

```
<property name="public" column="IS_PUBLIC" type="yes_no" formula="case when IS_PUBLIC is NULL then 'N' else IS_PUBLIC end"/>
```

When I try running a session.update(entityObject) which updates the above mentioned column, the change is not persisted in the database.

Im using hibernate 4.3.5 against TomEE appserver.

However on removing the formula, the update operation is working fine.
Please help me out..

Comment: have you closed your session ? if yes then it will throws error because update will work only when session is open.

Comment: No the session is not closed, and there are no exceptions or errors being thrown, the entity object is having the updated data, but it is not persisting in the database, once the formula is removed from the above mentioned property, the data is updated.